# How to remove https port after redirect on nginx from asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, host

I'm using an asp.net core app that calls the function `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and `app.UseHsts();`.
I can host the app on ubunto server on port 5000 for http and 5001 for https.

Now I need to host this with ngnix. This is my config:

```
server {
    
     listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   
    server_name myServername;
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 
    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }
```

Now when I call my page, it forwards me to `https://myServername:5001`. I need to change this port to be the standard port of https 443.

How should it be done?

Please note, that I have added my certificate there in the asp.net application.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it. My mistakes were:

1. No need to load the certificate in the asp.net app at the start.
2. Remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from the code.
3. Load the certificate at the ngnix server.

Following link is helpful:
https://github.com/tonysneed/Demo.AspNetCore-Nginx-Ssl

Answer (score 0):

I was pointing to plain http `localhost:5000` with nginx, as always, then was using certbot to secure connection. I have no idea why, but propably after .Net update it started to redirect from my domain to `***.5001` and of course throws error.

App was working with same settings for 1 year, and had no problem. I have checked it also in git history, there was `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`.
I rolled back, checked, it started working, and ran dotnet update last night again, and it caused problem of `307` redirect.

I have no idea why two versions of .Net works different but `/*app.UseHttpsRedirection();*/` did the trick.